# How can we access store API endpoints from javascript in Shopware 6.5?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I see **store-api-client.service.js** was deleted in 6.5, however the docs are still referencing it: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/fetching-data-with-javascript#call-the-store-api-from-the-storefront.

How should we access store API endpoints from javascript in 6.5?

Let's say a javascript plugin file that previously in 6.4 had:

```
        self._storeApiClient.get('/store-api/script/modigChatApp/initiate-chat', function (json) {
            const response = JSON.parse(json);

            if (!response.hasOwnProperty('subscriberToken')) {
                reject(response);
                return;
            }

            resolve(response.subscriberToken);
        });
```

How would this look like for 6.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quote the deprecation notice in the changelog:

> The `store-api` proxy route was removed. Please use the store-api directly.
> If that is not possible use a custom controller, that calls the `StoreApiRoute` internally.
> The `StoreApiClient` class from `storefront/src/service/store-api-client.service.js` was also removed, as that class relied on the proxy route.

That proxy route mentioned allowed you to use the store-api without explicit authorization, as the proxy used to authorize the request internally. This was deemed an undesirable workaround. If you want to use the store-api you'll have to [create a proper integration](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/system/integrationen), that will give you an access key. You then [use the access key for authorization](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/products/extensions/b2b-suite/guides/core/store-api) when you request the store-api.

As the changelog mentions, if you don't want to handle authorization, you can also create a custom controller that calls a store-api endpoint internally, bypassing the authorization. See the [original proxy controller](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.4/src/Storefront/Controller/StoreApiProxyController.php#L75) for reference.

Comment: In Shopware 6.4 my frontend plugin was calling this store-api proxy to retrieve the context token of the customer. Then I was able to retrieve the customer details with the backend using both the admin-api (to fetch the sales channel that contains the sw-access-key) and the store-api (to retrieve the customer id). How am I suppose to retrieve this context token in Shopware 6.5?